# React - My <video> tag becomes an <img> tag when page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, multer, mern

I built a MERN-stack application that uses Multer for image/vid uploading and storage.

Right now the accepted mimetypes are:

```
image/jpeg
image/jpg
image/png 
image/gif
video/mp4
```

The functionality works. The client can upload files of any of those types and all gets saved and rendered properly.

There is an **Index** page displaying all uploads (both images and videos), and each has a **Show** page.

At first the client wanted only images, so to render them all I needed was an `<img>` tag.

Afterwards, he asked that the mp4's be allowed as well.  So I used `slice()` to get the last 3 letters of the image name's string, to determine the filetype:

```
// Example: imageData = exampleImage.gif
imageData.slice(imageData.length - 3)  // returns 'gif'
```

And then I used a ternary operator inside the JSX to render `<video>` instead of `<img>` if that returns `'mp4'`.  I do this on both **Index** and **Show**.

The bug: If I refresh from **Index**, the page refreshes fine.  If I refresh on **Show**, the `<video>` becomes `<img>` which breaks it.

#### **Index Code**

```
{
  commission && commission.imageData.slice(commission.imageData.length - 3) !== "mp4" ?
  <CardImg     // Reactstrap tag
    top
    style={styles.image}
    src={commission.imageData}
    alt="Commission Image" 
  />
  :
  <video
    src={commission.imageData}
    alt="Commission Video"
    style={styles.video}
    autoPlay={true}
    loop
  />
}
```

#### **Show Code**

```
{
  imageData && imageData.slice(imageData.length - 3) !== "mp4" ?
  <img
    src={`../../${imageData}`}
    alt="Commission Display"
    style={styles.image}
  />
  :
  <video
    src={`../../${imageData}`}
    alt="Commission Video"
    style={styles.image}
    autoPlay={true}
    loop
  />
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

NOTE: I tried to reverse that ternary to be `if === "mp4"` and swapped the `<video>` and `<img>` but that didn't work.

---

### **Update**

**Show** displays an object called `showCommission`, which is a property of `commission` (the full list of commissions).

The redux data tree looks like:

```
commission
  commissions: []
  showCommission: {}
  loading: false
```

Redux code for `commission`:

```
import {etc} from 'etc';

const initialState = {
  commissions: [],
  showCommission: {},
  loading: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case COMMISSIONS_LOADING:
    case COMMISSION_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };

    case GET_COMMISSIONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        commissions: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };

    case ADD_COMMISSION:
      return {
        ...state,
        commissions: {
          pager: { ...state.commissions.pager },
          pageOfCommissions: [...state.commissions.pageOfCommissions, action.payload]
        }
      };

    case SHOW_COMMISSION:
      return {
        ...state,
        showCommission: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };

    case DELETE_COMMISSION:
      return {
        ...state,
        commissions: {
          pager: { ...state.commissions.pager },
          pageOfCommissions: state.commissions.pageOfCommissions.filter(c => c._id !== action.payload)
        }
      };
      
    case ADD_COMMISSION_FAIL:
    case EDIT_COMMISSION:
    case EDIT_COMMISSION_FAIL:
    case DELETE_COMMISSION_FAIL:
      return { ...state };

    default:
      return state;
  };
};
```

Component code (to see loading spinner)

```
class CommissionShowPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      redirectToCommissions: false
    };
  };

  static propTypes = {
    showCommission: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteCommission: PropTypes.func,
    commission: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.props.showCommission(id);
    if(this.state.redirectToCommissions) {
      this.setState({
        redirectToCommissions: false
      });
    };

    console.log(this.props.commission.showCommission)
  };

  handleDelete(id) {
    const result = window.confirm("Delete this commission?");
    if(result) {
      this.props.deleteCommission(id);
      this.setState({
        redirectToCommissions: true
      });
    };
  };

  render() {
    const redirectToCommissions = this.state.redirectToCommissions;
    const { _id, imageData, title, price, description } = this.props.commission.showCommission;
    const { loading } = this.props.commission;
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.user;

    if(loading) {
      return <h1 style={styles.loading}><Spinner style={styles.spinner} color="primary" /></h1>
    } else {
      return (
        <div style={styles.container}>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12} sm={12} lg={6} xl={6}>
                {
                  imageData && imageData.slice(imageData.length - 3) !== "mp4" ?
                  <img
                    src={`../../${imageData}`}
                    alt="Commission Display"
                    style={styles.image}
                  />
                  :
                  <video
                    src={`../../${imageData}`}
                    alt="Commission Video"
                    style={styles.image}
                    autoPlay={true}
                    loop
                  />
                }
              </Col>
              <Col className="show-pg-adjust">
                <h1><span style={styles.softenTone}>Title: </span>{ title }</h1>
                <h3>
                  {
                    price ? 
                    <div><span style={styles.softenTone}>Sold for: </span>${price}</div>
                    : null
                  }
                </h3>
                <h3><span style={styles.softenTone}>About this piece: </span></h3>
                <p>
                  { description }
                </p>
                <br/>
                {
                  isAuthenticated ?
                  <div>
                    <Link to={`/edit-commission/${_id}`}>
                      <Button
                        style={styles.userButton}
                        outline
                        color="warning"
                        className="user-btn"
                      >Edit Details
                        </Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Button
                      style={styles.userButton}
                      outline
                      color="danger"
                      className="user-btn"
                      onClick={() => this.handleDelete(_id)}
                    >Delete this Commission
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                  : null
                }
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
          { redirectToCommissions ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null }
        </div>
      )
    }
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  commission: state.commission,
  user: state.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { showCommission, deleteCommission })(CommissionShowPage);
```

Comment: If you console.log `imageData` upon refresh, what do you get? Chances are that `imageData` is not set to what you expect it to be at this point in the render.

Comment: Just tried it.  I'm getting `undefined` though the images still render.  Even the gifs..

Comment: I'm console.logging the entire data object the image belongs to, and it is blank when I refresh the page.  I have `loading` spinner wheel in place to not display things until they are loaded.  Is refreshing bypassing this?

Comment: Try adding a `return <div>Loading or Not image</div>` statement when `imageData` is undefined (or falsy really). It is probably just re-rendering when the value does come in. At least this will prevent unexpected behaviour and let you know when there is no `imageData` at all.  Edit: sorry your comment above was posted seconds before this one. See the next one.

Comment: hard to say without seeing the condition in which the spinner needs to appear. Update your original post with that spinner included and where `imageData` is coming from.

Comment: Updated now.  I discovered that the Index page has the same behavior, when I refresh it.  I just didn't realize because it wasn't breaking the videos displayed like on Show page.  But I must've done something wrong for this to happen. Hope I included everything relevant

Comment: It's still hard to say... My best bet is that your `imageData` is still undefined at the point in which you try chose to render an image or a video. I'd add the check for falsy `imageData` in the if block where you check if it's still loading and see what happens.

Comment: Hey @theJuls, I been experimenting.  I console log the data on the Index and Show page.  When the app is first visited, the console log shows an empty object, despite redux telling me the data/state is there.  If I click around the site, the console shows the requierd objects.  Then if I f5 refresh, the console shows empty objects again, and it only screws with the mp4s and not the images.  I tried a solution with localstorage but that.. only works.. sometimes.  I'm lost.  Probably need another SO post.  Thanks for the tip though, you helped me get this far.